# Sharing AWS user ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am wanting to share a Lambda Layer with someone and by doing so I will give them it's ARN which will contain my AWS accounts 12 digit ID.

Is there any risk associated with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you trust the party you're sharing the `Lamda ARN` with.

The risk of sharing your account ID is limited to what permissions you have granted for services.

The [AWS Account Identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html) documentation states that:

> The AWS account ID is a 12-digit number, such as 123456789012, that you use to construct Amazon Resource Names (ARNs). When you refer to resources, such as an IAM user or an Glacier vault, the account ID distinguishes your resources from resources in other AWS accounts.

Someone you've shared the account ID with could manipulate ARN's but without permission to access that resource there is no issue.

Bottom line, if you have tight controls that limit external access to resources (in your case the Lambda layer) you should be fine.

Comment: I was wanting to share the Lambda Layer publically. So implicit trust won't be a thing I have.
When you say manipulate ARN's do you just mean changing strings to try and find other resources?

Comment: Yes, ARN's are built off of the account ID.

Answer (score 0):

While it is generally not recommended to publish your Account ID (eg in StackOverflow questions), it is not terrible if other people know it.

The security of your AWS services is tied to **credentials**, not the account ID.

Knowing your account ID simply makes it easier for attacks to attempt to probe your account, especially if they know some of the services you are using. For example, they could look for publicly accessible Amazon SQS queues, knowing that they belong to your account.

If you are intentionally working with other people who wish to tie-in to your account, you can certainly share the ARN.